# Protobuf - Replacing a generic Collection

Tags: c#, .net-core, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm using C# in .Net Core 3.1. I have a class, used in existing projects / other APIs:

```cs
/// <summary>Class representing a Result Set (data coming from a result page,
/// plus the total count of the records coming from all the resulting pages) </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The class type of the result set</typeparam>
public class PagedResult<T>
{
    /// <summary> Total number of rows in the result set </summary>
    public long TotalRows { get; set; }

    /// <summary> IList containing the data of the requested page's result set  </summary>
    public IList<T> PageData { get; set; } = new List<T>();
}
```

I use this as the return type of many messages (basically every paged query).

How do I replace something like this in gRPC / Protobuf?

I can think of something along the lines of:

```
message PagedResult
{
  int32 total_rows = 1;
  repeated google.protobuf.Any page_data = 2;
}
```

But this will require me to treat every single result as different.
The alternative is to create a new message for each `page_data` type:

```
message MyEntityPagedResult
{
  int32 total_rows = 1;
  repeated MyEntity page_data = 2;
}
```

I know that protobuf does not support inheritance, but is there a way to manage this kind of response without inserting a lot of boilerplate in the proto? Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: You could consider using protobuf.net, I think that handles generics and inheritance just fine. I have not used it with gRPC, but there is a protobuf-net.Grpc package.

Comment: Indeed, with protobuf-net.Grpc, whack some [ProtoContract]/[ProtoMember(N)] attributes on there, and: you're done. The gRPC boundary can be described via an interface, job done

Answer (score 1):

[image]

---

May you can try to use Any keyword in your shell protobuf like this

```
message MyEntityPagedResult
{
  int32 total_rows = 1;
  any page_data = 2;
}
```

And your C# Client and Server side you can change this Any type like this

```
// Read Person message from detail.
if (status.page_data.Is(__YourClassType__))
{
    var person = status.page_data.Unpack<__YourClassType__>();
    ...
}
```

Note: At this solution, **YourClassType** have to define in proto as message class. this can  In my opinion there isnt any way to achive like  type in proto file :/

Edit:
This link also can give detail information about your problem. :)
Have a good coding :D

Comment: Thanks! It's a route I'm going to try, mainly because for corporate reasons I would like to stick to "Microsoft only" as much as possible, so I can't use Protobuf.Net (which seems very, _very_ nice).

Comment: I am very happy to help your problem. By the way this solution a bit hard butcreate a structure and hierarchy in protocols. As additinaly, I forget the link of  images link that I showed above.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/protobuf?view=aspnetcore-5.0